# How to get an a String from an array list of objects in java?

Tags: java, arrays, object, arraylist

I am having the user input an index. That index will be used to find a particular object called Movie in the list array called `movieList`. In that object i want to find the value of `genreOfMovie` and convert it to `String`.

I am using this line of code:

`Movie genreOfMovie = (Movie) movieList.get(Integer.parseInt(index) - 1);`

to set the veritable to what the user is looking for.

However when i run the program I dont get a string of a genre , what i get is some thing similar to `database.Movie@71aa1ce9`. Database if the name of the program and Movie is the name of the object so what is `@71aa1ce9` and how do i change this like

```
Movie genreOfMovie = (Movie) movieList.get(Integer.parseInt(index) - 1);
```

of code to print some sort of string like action because that is what was stored in there.

```
      String index  = TxtSearch.getText();
      Movie genreOfMovie = (Movie) movieList.get(Integer.parseInt(index) - 1);
      int counter = 0;
      do {
          counter++;
      } while (CbxGenres.getComponent(counter) != genreOfGame.toString());
```

Comment: Side note: it is a bad idea to directly parse a string and assume it represents a valid index in a list. Input coming directly from a user should **always** be handled with great care. You should: handle at least two error cases (input is not a number; parsed number is not a valid index)

Comment: besides other things already mentioned, you can't compare strings directly, better you use `.equals()` method: `CbxGenres.getComponent(counter).equals(genreOfGame.toString())`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to override the `toString()` method in your Movie class.  Here, you can assemble a description of the object using its instance fields as well as any other String.

```
public class Movie {
    private String name;
    private String genre;

    ...

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return genre;
        // alternatively, you can concatenate data into a String and return that, e.g. return name + " (" + genre + ")"
    }
}
```

On a side note, why doesn't your `movieList` have a generic type, e.g. `List<Movie>` ?

Comment: i am sorry i am very new to this, what does @Override actually do ? And how does  concatenating data in this case work?

Comment: `@Override` indicates that you're explicitly overriding a method from an ancestor.  If you annotate a method with this, but you're not actually overriding anything - maybe through a typo - the compiler will complain.

Comment: You could make your `toString()` method body look like this: `return "Movie: " + name` - this concatenates the String literal `Movie: `  with the name of the movie held by the Movie object.

Comment: Just to clarify, in my case i need to go to my object class Movie and enter 

@Override
public String toString() {
return genreOfMovie;
}

Comment: I've updated the example.  Another side note: you don't need to call it genreOfMovie, just genre - it's a property of a Movie, so you're essentially repeating yourself.

Comment: It works however my object has more than one variable eg
`nameOfMovie
genreOfGenre
 nameOfDirector`
it is very important to keep the data speared because I want to write the information back into text boxes because this is a part of an editing method .

Comment: Those should be separate instance variables in your Movie objects.  `toString()` isn't changing anything, it's just creating a new string that represents those fields as a single string that describes your object.

Comment: You should probably check the MVC pattern, it might help you organise your thoughts and design.

Comment: What im trying to do is have the user input an index of "record" want to append. The index will be used to look at a specific object in the array list. Everything stored in that object will be written to the input from.  The user will then be able to append their input and write it back to the same object. What I'm stuck on is the taking data from the object and adding it to the from controls. I am very sorry for pestering you.

Comment: I think you should ask a separate question if you're stuck on this.

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing is printing the String interpretation of the `Movie` object. What you want, is create your own string interpretation. You do this by overriding the toString() method in your movie object and returning the genre.

An example:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
   return this.genre;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

"@71aa1ce9" is name of object instance

```
Movie genreOfMovie = (Movie)
```

this is instance of one movie, to get genre you probably need to call some method on movie it self .. like .getGenre() or something like that